# How to get all opened forms call Sub with same name under each form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have an application with several forms(frm1, frm2...). Under each form there is a sub method: sub1. Is that possible to create a method in module to get all opened forms and made then run frm1.sub1, frm2.sub1...?
I already know that My.Application.OpenForms can find all opened form. But how to use this for next step? Since there are bunch of forms I can't name the form like this one by one.
'$'

```
        Dim frm As Form

        For Each frm In My.Application.OpenForms

            If frm Is My.Forms.TheFormINeed Then
              'do something
            end if
```

This may sounds newbie. Please help me.

Comment: You would either need to use late-binding or else cast each form as a type that had that method as a member. That could mean defining an interface with that method as a member and then implementing it in each form class.  It could also mean using `TryCast` multiple times. That said, what are you actually trying to achieve, as opposed to how you're trying to achieve it? Why do you have this "common" method and need to call it on all forms in the first place?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for your reply. I am working on a task to make forms switch between two language. Since different form have different structure I create ‘SwitchLan’ method in each form to change language. Which only share same name but content are different.

Comment: That sounds like a job for an interface. That said, would it not be better to simply use the globalisation and localisation functionality built into the Framework? That way, setting a single property for the application will update every form automatically.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney. It is a job to translate application's interface. I am not familiar with globalization and localization functionality. I use .resx file to store translations. And the method every form contained is the one I use to make the change. Can you explain more about "setting a single property for the application will update every form automatically"?

Comment: If you're not familiar with globalisation and localisation then the thing to do is research those topics.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use overrides to solve this question in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If all the subs you want to run are present in all the forms, then

```
For Each frm In My.Application.OpenForms
    CallByName(frm, "sub1", CallType.Method, Nothing)
Next
```

should do the trick.

Bear in mind of course that your main form may not have the sub, so you can use If..Then etc to include or exclude particular forms of course.

You can name forms by the way by setting the.Name property

Comment: Thank you! This is also an method I though of. But in the end I chose to create an Sub method: m1 in Class allforms which inherits from system.Window.Forms.Form. And let all other forms in my project overrides this m1 method. In this case I can use Dim f As allforms and use f.m1 to call that method.

Comment: Yep. that as well :-)